# Can I manipulate the DOM from a service?

Tags: angular

My application has many components connected to a single service that's responsible for sending out HTTP requests, if a request comes back with an error I want to handle that in one location, the service class, and handle it by showing a pop-up message or showing the error in a div element. Can I manipulate the DOM from a service class? If not then what's the ideal way to handle errors, should I be handling them from the components that initiate these requests? Or maybe I'd send the handling to the parent component from the service?

Here's my architecture:
[image]

Comment: create a global error handler. use an HTTP interceptor to implement a retry policy

Comment: Expose the error as an Observable in your service and allow the components to subscribe to it.